# Insert a chart in excel using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, exceljs

I want the chart in excel according to the data in the table. I have tried with canvas but canvas giving only image inside the excel. Please suggest some examples are libraries to use in NodeJs to insert a chart in excel . I have attached a picture below, with the table data chart needs to be inserted in the excel using NODEJS. Please suggest some solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]